# IPv6 Postfix can receive emails but cannot send

Tags: postfix, gmail, email-server

I installed postfix mta and configure to work with IPv6.
I tested sending an email from gmail to my vps and the email has been received but when i want to send an email to gmail i get timeout like below:

```
Sep  6 05:55:59 vpsunder10 postfix/smtp[9613]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4002:c01::1b]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 05:56:29 vpsunder10 postfix/smtp[9613]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400c:c02::1a]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 05:56:59 vpsunder10 postfix/smtp[9613]: connect to alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:400c:c03::1b]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 05:57:29 vpsunder10 postfix/smtp[9613]: connect to alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4013:c01::1b]:25: Connection timed out
Sep  6 05:57:59 vpsunder10 postfix/smtp[9613]: connect to alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2a00:1450:4001:c02::1b]:25: Connection timed out
```

As i see from the logs MTA tries to connect on port 25 which i think is closed.
Any ideas what is the problem?

Comment: Maybe your IPv6 provider blocks port 25 outgoing, just to be on the safe side?

Comment: i was thinking about this and now i'm sure that the port is blocked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port 25 is indeed filtered by HE.net because of abuse. See [this](https://www.tunnelbroker.net/forums/index.php?topic=2782.0) thread. For sake of reference, I pasted the post below:

> Due to an increase in email abuse, new non-BGP tunnels now have SMTP
>   blocked by default.  If you are a Sage, you can re-enable SMTP by
>   visiting the tunnel details page for that specific tunnel and
>   selecting the 'Unblock SMTP' option under the Advanced tab.  Because
>   this is now also being abused, we've disabled SMTP for new accounts
>   for now, and the Sage removal is not available for those.  If you need
>   SMTP (tcp/25), please email ipv6@he.net and explain your need for it. 
>   SMTP-MSA (tcp/587) is unaffected.  Existing tunnels have not been
>   filtered.
>
> This does not affect certification e-mail tests, since that traffic is
>   still explicitly permitted.
>
> Here's the matrix of how the blocking is implemented, since people
>   seem to be a little confused. Account Date    Tunnel Date Certification
>   Level SMTP Status Before this post    Before this post    Any Not filtered
>   Before this post  After this post Not Sage    Filtered Before this
>   post  After this post Sage    Option to unfilter under 'Advanced' After
>   this post n/a Not Sage    Filtered.  Contact ipv6@he.net if needed, with
>   your use justification.  Do note, non-Sages will likely need more
>   detailed justification. After this post   n/a Sage    Filtered.  Contact
>   ipv6@he.net as above, with your use justification.

Comment: Is he using Hurricane Electric?